# ar introduces undefined reference

Tags: linker, unix-ar

I'm trying to figure out how to use static libraries, but the most trivial example fails:

```
//foo.c
int func(int i) {
  return i+1;
}
//main.c
int func(int i);
int main() {
  return func(41);
}
```

Compiling `foo.c` and `main.c` works:

```
gcc -Wall -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -Wall -o main.o -c main.c
```

Archiving `foo.o` does not complain either:

```
ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o
```

But Linking fails with an undefined reference to `func`:

```
ld libfoo.a main.o
ld -L. -lfoo main.o
```

both give me:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `func'
```

I get a similar error if I take the detour via `gcc` to link:

```
gcc libfoo.a main.o
gcc -L. -lfoo main.o
```

give me:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `func'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong here? According to all manuals and search engines I read/used this is the way to use static libraries.

---

Edit: Mind that `gcc foo.o main.o` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trying stupid stuff, the most stupid idea was the solution: `ld` wants the object files first, **then** the archives. Yay!

```
gcc libfoo.a main.o  // fails
gcc main.o libfoo.a  // works
```

The same goes if you specify the library with `-L.` and `-lfoo`: Where you put `-L` doesn't matter apparently, but where you put `-lfoo` matters to the same extent as if you specify the `.a` file directly.